# cannot center three divs with css

Tags: css

I would like to center three images horizontally.

```
.music {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-image: url('image/music1.png');
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.music2 {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-image: url('image/music2.png');
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.music3 {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
background-image: url('image/music3.png');
margin: 0 auto;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}

.main_content {
height: auto;
margin: auto;
width:100%;
background-color:#b0e0e6;
}
```

and the obvious html

```
 <div class="main_content">
    <a href="documents.php"><div class="documents"></div></a>
    <a href="music"><div class="music"></div></a>
    <a href="photos"><div class="photos"></div></a>
</div>
```

The css keeps everything at the left hand side rather than centering. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: .main_content{text-align: center;}

Answer (score 2):

`margin: 0 auto` only centers block level elements with defined widths (like `<div>`'s, `<p>`'s, or inline elements - like `<a>`'s with `display: block`)

If you want to center an `inline-block` element or elements, you must use `text-align: center` on their parent.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your class names do not match; currently 'music2' and 'music3' has no HTML elements to be applied to.

change 'music2' and 'music3' to 'documents' and 'photos', then all 3 divs will be horizontally aligned.